# ASP.MVC TypeScript with DataTables script

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, typescript, datatables

At first I have html page without paging and sorting columns. After I change page and controller for sorting and paging used http://datatables.net/.

My PrototypeViewModel.ts:

```
class PrototypeViewModel {
prototypes: KnockoutObservable<any>;
selectPrototype: KnockoutObservable<any>;
editPrototype: KnockoutObservable<any>; 
succeeded: KnockoutObservable<any>;

constructor() {
    this.prototypes = ko.observable();
    this.selectPrototype = ko.observable();
    this.editPrototype = ko.observable(new Prototype());        
    this.succeeded = ko.observable(false);
}

getFiles(url: string, onError: (message: string) => {}) {
    (<any>this).invokeAjax(url, null, (data) =>
    {
        if (!data.succeeded) {
            onError(data.message);
        } else {
            this.prototypes(data.prototypes);
        }
    });
}

invokeAjax(url: string, params, callback: (result: any) => {}) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: params,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: (data) => {
            callback(data);
        },
        error: (data) => {
            this.succeeded(false);
        }
    });
}
```

javascript file:

```
<script src="@Url.Content(@"~/js/jquery.form.js")"></script>  
<script src="@Url.Content(@"~/js/knockout.mapping-latest.js")"></script>  
<script src="@Url.Content(@"~/ts/PortotypeViewModel.js")"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/dataTables/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/dataTables/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/dataTables/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/css/theme.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = null;
$(function () {
    vm = new PrototypeViewModel();

    GridNew();
    //GridOld();

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});

function GridOld() {
    vm.getFiles('@Url.Action("GetFiles", "Prototype")', function (errMessage) {            
        showWrating(errMessage);
    });
}
```

I'm change GridOld() to GridNew() with dataTable script, but i don't know how used tipe script with GridNew() function. Please help.

```
function GridNew() {        
    $(function () {
        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("AjaxHandler", "Prototype")",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ]
        });
    });
}
....
```

Comment: Side-note: your `GridNew` method has a DOM ready handler in it. That is not needed as the calling code is already in a DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

since you've decided to use TypeScript in your project, you may find that certain functions will not have intellisense support or are underlined in visual studio as  a red squiggly line because you're trying to use a library without the typed definitions.
you can get those [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.dataTables/jquery.dataTables.d.ts) or find the relevant nuget package for it.

also, since typeScript is just a super set of javascript, you can just call the normal javascript functions.